# How can I put a view center in any orientation

Tags: iphone, ipad, interface

I am designing the interface of my ipad app now, and i want to put a view on the center of the rootview. My code is:

```
CGRect ret = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds), bounds.size.width / 2,     bounds.size.height / 2); 

newViewController.view.frame = ret;
newViewController.view.center = self.view.center;

self.newViewController = newViewController;
[self.view addSubview:_newViewController.view];
```

the result is what I want as below:

[image]

but when I rotate to the landscape, it turns to be:

[image]

I want to know why it does not keep in the center as I have set and how can I make it works? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
youView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|
                                                 UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin| 
                                                 UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin| 
                                                 UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
youView.autoresizesSubviews= YES;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use XIBs make mask for your subviews as shown here:

[image: Center without resizing of subviews]

or here:

[image: Center with resizing of subview]

If you prefer to use code use posted one by @adali.

Answer (score 1):

use auto resizing mask to keep it in center

Comment: see this  http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/79917-uiviewcontroller-segmentcontrol.html